# Define globaly DisplayFormatString for ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to define globally a couple of standard format strings for numbers to be used across my ASP.NET project to format number on ASPxGridViews.

What I would like is to define somewhere something like:

```cs
 public static String defaultQuantyFormat="#,#.00000"
 public static String defaultAmountFormat="#,#.00"
```

Then to have in my aspx code:

```xml
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="StrategyObjectsGridView" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="quantity" DisplayFormatString='<%# defaultQuantyFormat %>'>
        <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="amount" DisplayFormatString='<%# defaultAmountFormat %>'>
    </Columns>
</dx:ASPxGridView>
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Comment: what do you mean by globally?

Comment: I mean centrally, I define the string in one place, and them use it in all my pages, ensuring uniformity in the format across the project, and if I want to change the format there is a single point to change, and the format will change everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In code:

```
namespace Application.Settings
{
  public class FormatSettings
  {
    public const string DefaultQuanty="#,#.00000"
    public const string DefaultAmount="#,#.00"
  }
}
```

In markup:

```
<%@ Import NameSpace="Application.Settings" %>

...

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="quantity" 
  DisplayFormatString='<%# FormatSettings.DefaultQuanty %>'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Stick them in a class, make the namespace the same as the rest of the project...

```
public class MyClass
{
    public const string _DefaultQuantityFormat = "#,#.0000";
}
```

Then in your page

```
DisplayFormatString='<%# MyClass._DefaultQuantityFormat %>'
```

Comment: This solution does not work, when I try it I get the error: 

Parser Error Message: Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. DevExpress.Web.ASPxEditors.TextBoxProperties does not have a DataBinding event.

Source Error:

`Line 153:                    <PropertiesTextEdit DisplayFormatString='<%# TresModuleWeb.GlobalVars._DefaultAmountFormat %>'></PropertiesTextEdit>

Same is true for the solution from @Igor

Comment: Ok thought you'd sorted that as you were databinding in your example. Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11725752/aspxgridview-itemplate-and-eval